# Adding items to an array seems to break ngRepeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an array that I display using ngRepeat and I have a form at the bottom that enables adding to the said array. This is used to work in previous version of angular; The way items are tracked in ngRepeat have changed in newer versions of angular, so I'm not sure yet if this is a big, but when I push an item to an array, all the items seem to be binded to the same model.

This is how I add an item:

```
var vm = this;

this.items = [];

this.addItem = function(item) {
    vm.items.push(item);
}
```

and I loop over them like this:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in main.items track by $index">{{item.id}} - {{item.value}}</li>
</ul>
<hr>
<input ng-model="main.newItem.id" type="text" placeholder="id">
<input ng-model="main.newItem.value" type="text" placeholder="value">
<button ng-click="main.addItem(main.newItem)">Add Item</button>
```

Here is a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/BZowU9xCR8fod9AtzL1N?p=preview) demonstrating the issue.

Comment: That's normal: `newItem` is always the same object. Just copy it in the `addItem` function, for instance with `vm.items.push(angular.copy(item));`

Comment: Did you ever declare newItem inside your controller? You're referencing a main.newItem but I don't see it declared.

Comment: Didn't declare it, its not necessary to declare it.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer by user [Blackhole](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2057033/blackhole)

Need to make a copy of the item before adding it to the array

```
vm.items.push(angular.copy(item));
```